# Событие Drop при перетаскивании

Tags: c#, drag-n-drop, winforms

Есть ли такое событие, которое возникает в том компоненте, который перетаскивают, в то время когда его кидают. Самый близкий по значению это OnQueryContinueDrag, но он возникает перед действием, а мне нужно после. Или хотя бы знать эффект перетаскивания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До чего нравится этот форум. Как только проблему свою опишу, сразу же нахожу/придумываю решение. На большинство своих вопросов отвечаю сам. Надеюсь, хоть не напрасно будет, кому-нибудь пригодится. Сделал так: в обработчике OnGiveFeedback запоминаю DragDropEffects, а уже в OnQueryContinueDrag в зависимости от эффекта произвожу те или иные действия(в данном случае удаление перетаскиваемого объекта).